# python оптимизация циклов

Tags: python, циклы

Как мне оптимизировать цикл, чтобы он работал намного быстрее?

```
import keyboard
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from Xlib import display

def move_left():
    keyboard.send('right')
def move_right():
    keyboard.send('left')
def exist_branch(x, y):
    box = (x, y - 1 * 85, x + 1, y)
    im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
    x, y = im.size
    result = []
    for i in range(0, 1):
        r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((0, y - 1 - i * 85))
        summa = r + g + b
        if summa == 301 or summa == 289 or summa == 244 or summa == 210 or summa == 248 or summa == 217:
            result.append(False)
        else:
            result.append(True)
    return result
def get_mouse():
    while True:
        data = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data
        x = data["root_x"]
        y = data["root_y"]
        print
        '%s,%s - %s' % (str(x), str(y), exist_branch(x, y))
def main():
    start_x = 1033
    start_y = 715
    while True:
        branches = exist_branch(start_x, start_y)
        branches1 = exist_branch(start_x, 800)
        for elem in branches:
             if elem:
                for elem in branches1:
                 if elem:
                  move_left()
                 else:
                     move_right()
             else:
                 move_right()
try:
    # get_mouse()
    main()
except:
    print
    'Exit..'
```

Comment: Опишите в вопросе что делает ваш код. Подозреваю, что у вас создание скриншота занимает львиную часть времени работы скрипта

Comment: Скажем так, есть игра в которой нужно уворачиваться от веток туда сюда, для этого создается скриншот и с него читается наличие пикселей цвета веток над головой персонажа, а потом выполняется действие